# Remove fields from elements of inner array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Say I have:

```
db.test.insert({foos: [{bars: [{}, {}]}]});
db.test.insert({foos: [{bars: [{}, {}]}]});
```

Now I want to remove all bars-fields of all foos. How do I do that?

```
db.test.update({}, {$unset: {"foos.bars": 1}});
```

and

```
db.test.update({}, {$pull: {"foos.bars": {}}});
```

doesn't do anything.

```
db.test.update({}, {$pull: {"foos.$.bars": {}}});
```

gives error:

"Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array."

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an exist-query on the subdocument in the array seemed to do the trick:

```
db.test.remove();
db.test.insert({foos: [{bars: [{"baz": 1} ]}]});
db.test.insert({foos: [{bars: [{"baz": 1} ]}]});
db.test.find({'foos.bars': {$exists: true}}).count();
db.test.update({'foos.bars': {$exists: true}}, {$unset: {'foos.$.bars': 1}}, false, true);
db.test.find({'foos.bars': {$exists: true}}).count();
```